# JavaMailSender: Authentication failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail, jhipster

I Couldn't send mail for an email with `.` like `example.ca@gmail.com`, but something like `example@gmail.com` is successful.

I used the spring helper and smtp.gmail.com setting to send mail.

```
        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(content, isHtml);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            log.debug("Sent email to User '{}'", to);
        } catch (MailException | MessagingException e) {
            log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
        }
```

error log:

```
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416873+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-08-31 04:06:27.416  WARN 4 --- [ travoxi-task-1] com.travoxi.service.MailService          : Email could not be sent to user 'example.ca@gmail.com'
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416890+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416893+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416894+00:00 app[web.1]: 534-5.7.14 qNoy6Lu4AF50xBC1hVOvMq5I5WERrCjcVtqcfyg5diaafRcCIxfAL0CTgx5Mf9FPT3o1z
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416894+00:00 app[web.1]: 534-5.7.14 ouQgv4Ywttz25NL7CwTx7It0n9Hycl4RsHvptxU48jLZLiH4amfxH1YBgFzKWnbW>
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416895+00:00 app[web.1]: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416896+00:00 app[web.1]: 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416896+00:00 app[web.1]: 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a185sm12790018qkg.128 - gsmtp
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416896+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416897+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440)
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416897+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
2021-08-31T04:06:27.416897+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
```

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en usually dot(.) doesn't matter in Gmail email. May be you can try sending without . to try if that works

Comment: Try checking the spam folder of example.something@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says problem with your credentials. Try to verify the same credentials are working from browser first.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
```

Comment: but I can send to other emails like `example@gmail.com` successful. only error when I send to `example.something@gmail.com`

Comment: try checking example.something@gmail.com 's spam